# Need to access dynamic controls ids inside the update panels

Tags: c#, asp.net, page-lifecycle

I am populating dynamic controls inside the update panel. The steps are

Step 1: Dynamic controls are populated inside dynamic table like this which is inside panel

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlShowDDF" runat="server" Visible="False" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
</asp:Panel>
```

Step 2:

```
         protected void loadTable()
            {
                HtmlTable tblDDF = new HtmlTable();
                var objDDF = new ddf();

            var dsDdfDetail = "DataSet Loaded"
            if (dsDdfDetail.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                int RowsCount = dsDdfDetail.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < RowsCount; i++)
                {
                    HtmlTableRow tblNewRow = new HtmlTableRow();
                    HtmlTableCell tblDdfCell = new HtmlTableCell();
                    tblDdfCell1.Controls.Add(addCheckbox(dsDdfDetail.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()));
    //The addCheckbox function returns the checkbox with its text


        tblNewRow.Controls.Add(tblDdfCell);
                    tblDDF.Controls.Add(tblNewRow);
                }
            HtmlTableRow htFooterRow = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell htFooterCell = new HtmlTableCell();

            htFooterCell.Controls.Add(DelButton());
//DelButton() is written in below
                htFooterCell.Attributes.Add("class", "pnlFooterRow");
                htFooterCell.ColSpan = 2;
                htFooterRow.Cells.Add(htFooterCell);
                tblDDF.Controls.Add(htFooterRow);
                }
            pnlShowDDF.Controls.Add(tblDDF);
            pnlShowDDF.Visible = true;
        }
protected Button DelButton()
    {
        var btnDelete = new Button();
        btnDelete.ID = "btnDelete";
        btnDelete.Text = "De-Allocate";
        btnDelete.Click += new EventHandler(btnDelete_Click);
        btnDelete.Attributes.Add("class", "button");
        btnDelete.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled;
        return btnDelete;
    }
```

Step 3 Need to access dynamic checkbox id from the btnDelete

```
void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Need to access the checkbox id's here
        foreach(Control chk in pnlShowDDF.Controls)
        {
            if(chk is CheckBox)
            {
               CheckBox chkbx= chk as CheckBox;
                if(chkbx.Checked)
                {
                   //Here i need to access the id's which i can't right now
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Step 4: i have recalled the loadTable function on OnInit but no gains

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
       base.OnInit(e);
        loadTable();
    }
```

What should be done so that i can access the checkbox id's ??

Comment: Have you tried with `FindControl`...?

Comment: Does the controls exist at this stage of the page? I will give it a try let see.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you add dynamic controls, you have to add them in `Page_Init` event and assign them proper IDs, so that when a postback occurs, those dynamic added controls are created again along with their values and will be accessible in other events, in your case `btnDelete_Click`.

So what you are missing is assigning IDs to the table cells and rows, I hope you are assigning ID to the checkboxes.

**========================= EDIT ============================**

Here is the code that is working with me, `btnDelete_Click` has good enough changes in it. I am getting the checkboxes that I added in and if I check any of them, i get the value as true.

```
protected void loadTable()
    {
        HtmlTable tblDDF = new HtmlTable();
        //var objDDF = new ddf();

        //DataSet dsDdfDetail = new DataSet();
        //if (dsDdfDetail.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        //{
            //int RowsCount = dsDdfDetail.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                HtmlTableRow tblNewRow = new HtmlTableRow();
                HtmlTableCell tblDdfCell = new HtmlTableCell();
                tblDdfCell.Controls.Add(addCheckbox(i.ToString()));
                //The addCheckbox function returns the checkbox with its text


                tblNewRow.Controls.Add(tblDdfCell);
                tblDDF.Controls.Add(tblNewRow);
            }
            HtmlTableRow htFooterRow = new HtmlTableRow();
            HtmlTableCell htFooterCell = new HtmlTableCell();

            htFooterCell.Controls.Add(DelButton());
            //DelButton() is written in below
            htFooterCell.Attributes.Add("class", "pnlFooterRow");
            htFooterCell.ColSpan = 2;
            htFooterRow.Cells.Add(htFooterCell);
            tblDDF.Controls.Add(htFooterRow);
        //}
        pnlShowDDF.Controls.Add(tblDDF);
        pnlShowDDF.Visible = true;
    }
protected Button DelButton()
    {
        var btnDelete = new Button();
        btnDelete.ID = "btnDelete";
        btnDelete.Text = "De-Allocate";
        btnDelete.Click += new EventHandler(btnDelete_Click);
        btnDelete.Attributes.Add("class", "button");
        //btnDelete.ViewStateMode = ViewStateMode.Enabled;
        return btnDelete;
    }
protected CheckBox addCheckbox(string id)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.ID = id;
        return chk;
    }
void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Need to access the checkbox id's here
        foreach (Control chk in pnlShowDDF.Controls)
        {
            if (chk is HtmlTable)
            {
                HtmlTable tbl = (HtmlTable)chk;

                foreach (HtmlTableRow row in tbl.Rows)
                {
                    foreach (HtmlTableCell cell in row.Cells)
                    {
                        foreach (Control chk1 in cell.Controls)
                        {
                            if (chk1 is CheckBox)
                            {
                                CheckBox chkbx = chk1 as CheckBox;
                                if (chkbx.Checked)
                                {
                                    //Here i need to access the id's which i can't right now
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes the addcheckbox(id) function not mention in above code is doing exactly that. I am assigning it. But still no gains

Comment: In btnDelete_Click can you verify that there are rows available in the table, tblDDF?

Comment: The debugger cannot reach the btnDelete_Click. Since this button is also dynamically created. Panel losses all controls on the click event.

Comment: This is strange, if you are assigning ID to btnDelete, than it must be rendered.

Comment: This is why i am stuck and have put the code on here, if something is missing

Comment: In loadTable() method, you have HtmlTableCell tblDdfCell = new HtmlTableCell();             tblDdfCell1.Controls.Add(addCheckbox(dsDdfDetail.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString()));      tblDdfCell1, is it typing mistake? as you have declared tblDdfCell and later using tblDdfCell1

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16538/discussion-between-shah-and-imran-balouch)